# F#: Reduce/aggregate a sequence or list in pairs

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I am fairly new to functional programming and have some problems with a list processing task. I have a collection of records like the following:

```
type TestRec = {
    Id : string
    Amount : int }
```

Now I want to remove all items in the list that build a pair with each other. For example if there are two items with the `Amount` of `7` and `-7` **both** items should be removed from the list. If there is a third element with `Amount = 7` it should stay in the list.

I hope you guys can understand what I am trying to do. This is what I came up with so far (but it does not work correctly yet):

```
let removeDoubles items =
    items
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun i -> Math.Abs(i.Amount))
    |> Seq.map snd
    |> Seq.filter (fun i -> Seq.length i = 1)
```

**Edit:**
The function that determines if two elements match with each other might be more complex than described above (`Math.Abs`). I thought it would be a good example with the `Amount` values but it could be any predicate function.

**Edit 2:**
In order to clarify some more I want to give a more realistic description of a possible related problem. You can imagine the calculation of an invoice where the list consists of all invoice positions. Now you want to remove all pairs of invoice positions that have for example the same 'article number', 'currency' and the prices evaluate to zero.

Maybe this example helps to explain my problem. I just thought there might be a more 'functional way' of solving this problem than having two loops running over the list and removing the elements like I would do in an imperative language.

Comment: So you basically want a new list/sequence back, with the amounts aggregated for each ID, removing the entry entirely if 0?

Comment: @Orbling No, not exactly I think. You have to forget the `Id`. That field is just a placeholder for any arbitrary data that might be part of the record. I basically want to search for pairs of elements that should be removed from the list.

Comment: So you just need to find integers that match in magnitude in the list, but differ in sign - and then remove them?

Comment: If the predicate is arbitrary, this is going to be at least `n^2` as each element is considered in turn and every other element evaluated as a potential partner.

Comment: I think you need to specify more information about the matching function.  In your example, if you've got amounts of 7, 7, and -7, do I need to cancel one of the 7s with the -7 (leaving one 7), or could I cancel the two 7s (leaving the -7).  In the more general setting, if I have a value, might there be more than one value that "cancels" it?

Comment: @Orbling Yes, that would be the case in this example. I just edited my question so far that those `Amount` values are just an example to find two matching elements. Basically it could be any function that identifies a pair in that list. I just thought that would be a good example.

Comment: @kvb the numbers 7,7 and -7 would leave one 7 in the sequence because the elements are supposed to be removed in pairs only.

Comment: From what you are saying, the sign is just immaterial, as opposed to a need to match the opposite sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abstract the idea of opposing pairs away, I define two functions.  One for relational equality (related) and one to define cancellations (opposite).

The function works by first grouping the related objects together and then partitioning them into opposing arrays.  These resulting arrays are then sliced according to the number of required cancellations.  Finally everything is concated together.

```
type TestRec = {
    Id : string;
    Amount : int;
}

let removeDoubles items related opposite =
    items
    |> Seq.groupBy related
    |> Seq.map (fun (key, values) -> 
        let t, f = values |> Seq.toArray |> Array.partition opposite
        if t.Length > f.Length then
            t.[.. t.Length - f.Length - 1]
        else
            f.[.. f.Length - t.Length - 1]
        )
    |> Seq.concat

let items = [
    {Id="first";Amount=7}; 
    {Id="seconds";Amount=7};
    {Id="we";Amount=4}; 
    {Id="negative";Amount= -7}
    ]

let test = removeDoubles 
               items 
               (fun x -> abs x.Amount) 
               (fun x -> x.Amount > 0)

printf "%A" test

System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Outputs

```
seq [{Id = "first";
      Amount = 7;}; {Id = "we";
                     Amount = 4;}]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Updated, based on your comment)

If you want to remove consecutive negating pairs, you can simply do:

```
let removePairs f items =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | a :: b :: t when f a b -> loop acc t
    | h :: t -> loop (h::acc) t
    | [] -> List.rev acc
  loop [] (List.ofSeq items)

items |> removePairs (fun {Amount=amtA} {Amount=amtB} -> amtA + amtB = 0)
```

Comment: I think my initial example was not too clear. It should be possible to have for example `Amounts` of [7;7;4] where no element would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, probably not so functional as other proposals, but should be efficient:

```
type R = {
    Id : int
    Amount : int
    }
let mkR id amount = {Id = id; Amount = amount}    

open System.Collections.Generic
let removePairs s : seq<R> = 
    // stores mapping: key -> corresponding nodes in result list
    let seen = Dictionary<_, LinkedList<LinkedListNode<R>>>() 
    // accumulates result
    let list = LinkedList<R>() 

    // check if paired element was already met
    // if yes - remove its first appearance from the result list
    let tryEliminate ({Amount = a} as el) = 
        // paired element will have different sign
        let key = -a
        match seen.TryGetValue key with
        | true, existing ->
            list.Remove(existing.First.Value) // Remove(LinkedListNode) works in O(1)
            existing.RemoveFirst()
            if existing.Count = 0 then seen.Remove key |> ignore
            true
        | _ -> 
            false

    let append ({Amount = a} as el) =
        let newNode = list.AddLast(el)
        let l = 
            match seen.TryGetValue a with
            | true, existing -> existing
            | false, _ ->
                let nodes = LinkedList()
                seen.Add(a, nodes)
                nodes
        l.AddLast(newNode) |> ignore

    for el in s do
        if not (tryEliminate el) then append el

    list :> _

let check source expected = 
    let result = 
        source
        |> List.mapi (fun i x -> {Id = i; Amount = x})
        |> removePairs 
        |> List.ofSeq
    if (result <> expected) then failwithf "Expected: %A, actual %A" expected result

check [1;1;-1;2] [mkR 1 1; mkR 3 2]
check [1;1;-1;-1] []
check [7;7;4] [mkR 0 7; mkR 1 7; mkR 2 4]
```